# Instalation throws 502 gateway error while connecting an external oracle database server

Tags: 7, database

I need to install Drupal 7.34 on **nginx** **web server** with **oracle 12** as database.

Oracle is listing in DB list. But after submitting the DB and server details, it fails. I am posting the error that I got while submitting the DB data.

```
[error] 963#0: *56 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: <ip>, server: , request: "POST /install.php?profile=standard&locale=en HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "<ip>", referrer: "http://<ip>/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en"
```

Comment: Can you tell me the process of connects,i mean how you can connect to oracle db.

Comment: Followed the steps mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/1298536 with drupal oracle driver. Normal oracle connection with Database name, username & password. In advance options, remote host, port and tablr prfix.

Comment: What machine or demon is"gateway" in your setup and what is in it's logs?